# Why I keep getting exception out of range when drawing lines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Start()
{
    Mesh meshprefab = meshPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    newVertices = meshprefab.vertices;

    for (int i = 0; i < newVertices.Length; i++)
    {
        DrawLine(newVertices[counter], newVertices[counter + 1], Color.red);
        DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
        DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 2], newVertices[counter], Color.red);

        counter = counter + 3;
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
```

The exception:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.

This is the complete script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject meshPrefab;
    public Vector3[] newVertices;
    public Vector2[] newUV;
    public int[] newTriangles;

    private List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector2> uvsList = new List<Vector2>();
    private List<int> trianglesList = new List<int>();
    private int counter = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        Mesh meshprefab = meshPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        newVertices = meshprefab.vertices;

        for (int i = 0; i < newVertices.Length; i++)
        {
            DrawLine(newVertices[counter], newVertices[counter + 1], Color.red);
            DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
            DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 2], newVertices[counter], Color.red);

            counter = counter + 3;
        }
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your "counter" initialize?

Comment: @Lotan Before the start initialized to 0. private int counter = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supouse that newVertices is an array of 4 positions [3] (0,1,2,3)

On your first loop you'll have

```
i = 0;
newVertices.Length = 4;
counter = 0;
```

so you're trying to do that:

```
DrawLine(newVertices[counter], newVertices[counter + 1], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 2], newVertices[counter], Color.red);
```

which is translated as:

```
DrawLine(newVertices[0], newVertices[1], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[1], newVertices[2], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[2], newVertices[0], Color.red);
```

So this first loop will work as you're not exceeding the newVertices lenght, which is 4. But what will happen on your second loop?

```
i = 1;
newVertices.Length = 4;
counter = 3;
```

so you're trying to do that:

```
DrawLine(newVertices[counter], newVertices[counter + 1], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 2], newVertices[counter], Color.red);
```

which is translated as:

```
DrawLine(newVertices[3], newVertices[4], Color.red);
DrawLine(newVertices[4], newVertices[5], Color.red); --> ERROR!!!!
DrawLine(newVertices[5], newVertices[3], Color.red); --> ERROR!!!!
```

You're code have an out of range error cause **newVertices[5]** is out of the newVertices.Length size.

Comment: I understand the problem. since I'm doing counter + 2 in the end there is no index 5. What is the solution then ? How can I draw the 3 lines of each 3 vertices from the list ? I have to mention that in my case in this case the List newVertices contains 350 items. And 350 divide by 3 is 116.666666666 so I'm not sure how can it be drawing triangles each 3 vertices since it's not equal in the end.

Comment: I also edited my question added the complete script. newVertices contains 350 items. Then how many triangles should be ?

Comment: If' I'm doing in my script adding the line: newTriangles = meshprefab.triangles; I see that there are 1158 triangles. Then I'm lost here. How do you calculate how many triangles will be draw according to the number of vertices ? 1158 / 3 ? This give 386 but there are 350 vertices.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi This is another question, and it depends if your lines could be part of more than one triangle? maybe one edge of one triangle is also the edge of another triangle.

Comment: You right I didn't think about lines that cant be for more then one triangle. Seems not easy to solve. Still not sure how the script should be solved with the exception. Maybe I need to make a new question.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi Yes, probably is better to make a new question with your "triangles problem". Will be new on the unity heap and people would be more "engaged" with the title! :D (btw remember that if you think this is the solution to your actual question, mark it, so other people can saw it as "solved")

Answer (score 1):

Take the line

```
DrawLine(newVertices[counter + 1], newVertices[counter + 2], Color.red);
```

So for i = 0; i<  newVertices.Length; ...

when i is the last one, how is it supposed to add 2 to it?? or 1 to it?

Shrinking it down if there were 3

```
0 ..  draw newVertices[1], newVertices[2]
1 .. draw newVertices[2], newVertices[3] // error there is no 3
2 .. draw newVertices[3], newVertices[4] // error there is no 3 or 4!
```

Comment: Then how the code should be ? First time counter is 0 so in the first line its drawing from 0 to 1 then from 1 to 2 then from 2 to 0. Next time counter is 3. So it's drawing from 3 to 4 then from 4 to 5 and then from 5 to 3.  What am I missing ?

Comment: so you want to do a loop that is to length -2 .. so theres your 2 spare at the end..